# How a reference type can be assigned to a structure in c#

Tags: c#, .net

```
Int I=7;
Int ? j= null;
```

Here we are able to assign a reference type(null) to a value type(j).
As this nullable thing comes under   System.Nullable namespace which is a structure.
How this is possible.??

Comment: Its a special case and designed that way

Comment: This should help you out understand it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272101/why-nullablet-is-a-struct

Comment: [Reading the source](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/nullable.cs) should probably be sufficient for working out how it works.

Comment: _"How a reference type can be assigned to a structure"_ - it is still not possible. `null` is not a 'reference type'. It can refer either a null reference of any reference types or the null value of nullable value types.

Answer (score 2):

`int ? j= null` is syntactic sugar.

This:

```
private void Foo()
{
    int? i = null;
}
```

this:

```
private void Foo()
{
    Nullable<int> i = null;
}
```

and this:

```
private void Foo()
{
    Nullable<int> i = new Nullable<int>();
}
```

compile into:

```
.method private hidebysig instance void  Foo() cil managed
{
  // Code size       10 (0xa)
  .maxstack  1
  .locals init ([0] valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<int32> i)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldloca.s   i
  IL_0003:  initobj    valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<int32>
  IL_0009:  ret
} // end of method Program::Foo
```

where

```
IL_0001:  ldloca.s   i
IL_0003:  initobj    valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<int32>
```

means initializing an instance of a structure.

Thus there is no null-reference and an object exists. One can access its readonly property `HasValue` without `NullReferenceException`.

```
int? i = null;
Console.WriteLine(i.HasValue);
```

gives

```
False
```

and

```
Console.WriteLine(i.Value);
```

throws not NullReferenceException, but **InvalidOperationException**.

Though

```
Console.WriteLine(i.GetType());
```

throws NullReferenceException.

Long story short, for `Nullable<T>` or `T?` `null` means **not** a `null-reference`, but an **instance** of `Nullable<T>` with `HasValue` set to false.

**BUT**

If you are looking for a **WAY**

**how a reference type can be assigned to a structure in c#**

try this:

```
class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Struct<int> @struct = new Class<int>(-1);
        Class<int> @class = new Struct<int>(-1);
    }
}

class Class<T>
{
    public T Value { get; }

    public Class(T value) => Value = value;

    public static implicit operator Struct<T>(Class<T> instance) => new Struct<T>(instance.Value);
}

struct Struct<T>
{
    public T Value { get; }

    public Struct(T value) => Value = value;

    public static implicit operator Class<T>(Struct<T> instance) => new Class<T>(instance.Value);
}
```

**Remember, it just looks as assignment, but before real assignment happens casting takes place.**

Answer (score 1):

The C# specification is clear on this point: the `null` keyword represents an expression that has no type. It is neither reference type nor value type nor pointer type. However, that expression is convertible to all of those types. There is no requirement that the compiler classifies all expressions as having a type, and in fact, it does not.

Any type can contain `null`

**1) For Reference Types:**
If the reference type variable contains `null` that means it is not pointing to anything on the heap. Reference type variable stored on the stack and may contain `null` or a reference to an actual heap object.

**2) For Value Types:** If the nullable value type variable contains `null` that means it does not hold any value within itself. Value type stored on the stack(in most cases) and can contain the direct value within itself or `null`.