# Assigning null value to nullable value type is equal to new Nullable<T> in c#?

Tags: c#, struct, null

Assigning null value to nullable value type is equal to `new Nullable<T>` in `c#`?

I've the following code:

```cs
int? num = null;
```

According to the [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5602796/7086678):

> The nullable type is a struct consisting of two fields: a bool and a T. When the value is null, the bool is false and the T has the default value. When the value is not null, the bool is true.

The default value for value types is set for the [`Value`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/98d47d5fc0f1b232869a9abd27729235fd7355b0/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Nullable.cs#L20) field in [`Nullable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1?view=net-7.0) struct. [^](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/98d47d5fc0f1b232869a9abd27729235fd7355b0/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Nullable.cs#L14-L17)

When I use the `int? num = null`, the `num` is equal to `new Nullable<int>();` and default value `0` is set for the `value`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I use the int? num = null, the num is equal to new Nullable(); and default value 0 is set for the value?

Yes, but you'll get an `InvalidOperationException` if you attempt to access the `Value` property of a `Nullable<T>` when it's `HasValue` property is `false`.

Eric Lippert wrote a two-posts series about Nullable types in his blog, I highly recommend reading it:

[Nullable micro-optimizations, part one](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/20/nullable-micro-optimizations-part-one/)

[Nullable micro-optimizations, part two](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/27/nullable-micro-optimization-part-two/)

More Information:

- [How does a Nullable type work behind the
  scenes?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5602800/7086678)
- [Why are Nullable considered a value
  type?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2031051/7086678)
- [how are nullable types implemented under the hood in
  .net?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2503832/7086678)
- [Nullable
  implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25629239/7086678)